# Python readline from pipe on Linux

Tags: python, pipe, readline

When creating a pipe with `os.pipe()` it returns 2 file numbers; a read end and a write end which can be written to and read form with `os.write()`/`os.read()`; there is no os.readline().  Is it possible to use readline?

```
import os
readEnd, writeEnd = os.pipe()
# something somewhere writes to the pipe
firstLine = readEnd.readline() #doesn't work; os.pipe returns just fd numbers
```

In short, is it possible to use readline when all you have is the file handle number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`os.fdopen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fdopen) to get a file-like object from a file descriptor.

```
import os
readEnd, writeEnd = os.pipe()
readFile = os.fdopen(readEnd)
firstLine = readFile.readline()
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew it had to be simple!

Answer (score 4):

Pass the pipe from `os.pipe()` to [`os.fdopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#index-465), which should build a file object from the filedescriptor.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to take a file descriptor (number) and turn it into a file object. The [`fdopen`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#file-object-creation) function should do that:

```
import os
readEnd, writeEnd = os.pipe()
readFile = os.fdopen(readEnd)
# something somewhere writes to the pipe
firstLine = readFile.readline()
```

Can't test this right now so let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

`os.pipe()` returns file descriptors, so you have to wrap them like this:

```
readF = os.fdopen(readEnd)
line = readF.readline()
```

For more details see http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fdopen

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here is a version that doesn't deadlock.

```
import os, threading

def Writer(pipe, data):
    pipe.write(data)
    pipe.flush()


readEnd, writeEnd = os.pipe()
readFile = os.fdopen(readEnd)
writeFile = os.fdopen(writeEnd, "w")

thread = threading.Thread(target=Writer, args=(writeFile,"one line\n"))
thread.start()
firstLine = readFile.readline()
print firstLine
thread.join()
```