# How to use readline() with a pipe returned by subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, readline

I'm calling a child process using `subprocess.Popen` (Python 2.x on a POSIX system). I want to be able to read the output of the child process using Python's `readline()` file object function. However, the stream available in `Popen.stdout` does not appear to have a `readline()` method.

Using the idea from [Python readline from pipe on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193779/python-readline-from-pipe-on-linux), I tried the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    [sys.executable, "child.py"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
status = os.fdopen(p.stdout.fileno())
while True:
    s = status.readline()
    if not s:
        break
    print s
```

However, the problem with this method is that *both* the `p.stdout` object and the new `status` object attempt to close the single file descriptor. This eventually results in:

```
close failed: [Errno 9] Bad file number
```

Is there a way to create a file object that "wraps" a previously created file-like object?

Comment: how do you get `p.stdout` that has `.fileno()` but no `.readline()` method?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's a good question. I just tried again and `p.stdout.readline()` works fine. It's possible that I had mistakenly tried `p.readline()`, which is sort of embarrassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `os.dup()` to create another file descriptor referring to the same pipe:

```
status = os.fdopen(os.dup(p.stdout.fileno()))
```

This way, `status` has its own file descriptor to close.

Comment: It's amazing how often simply *writing* a question makes the answer obvious.